# Почему не работает :hover?

Tags: hover

Задача - сделать таблицу - типа продукт-цена. При наведении на ячейку, кроме ссылки сбоку должна появляться метка. При этом ссылкой должно быть не только слово, но и сама ячейка) Без таблицы все работает) Что я делаю не так??

```css
td a {
 width: 100%;
}
.wp-450 {
visibility:  hidden;
padding-right: 5px;

}
.wp-450:hover {
visibility: visible;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="120%">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"><span style="font-size: 50px"><a href="..." style="color: #000"><img class="wp-450" src="ссылка на фото метки" width="10" height="44" />товар</a></span></td>
      
    </tr>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы использовали неверный селектор. Если Вам необходимо появление изображения по наведению на ссылку, устанавливайте `hover` непосредственно на неё, а не на картинку.

```css
td a {
 width: 100%;
}
.wp-450 {
visibility: hidden;
padding-right: 5px;

}
td a:hover .wp-450 {
visibility: visible;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="120%">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"><span style="font-size: 50px"><a href="..." style="color: #000"><img class="wp-450" src="ссылка на фото метки" width="10" height="44" />товар</a></span></td>
      
    </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Гениально! Вы меня спасли)))